# Docusign share integration key for multiple accounts

Tags: docusignapi

I'm experimenting with building an integration between my app and any DocuSign account.

If I create an integration key in my developer sandbox, go through the "go live" process will I be able to use that same integration key to authenticate on behalf of users of different DocuSign accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's right.
The Integration Key's account is the account that creates and manages it.
Any account in DocuSign (production accounts only after you go live) can use the IK.
Of course, users have to consent the first time they use a new IK in their account, but that's part of the OAuth process.

So no, nothing to worry about, the IK is global in the same environment and can be used by any account.